# How to access/output this json_decode multi dimensional associative array with PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am trying to access and output the JSON response:

1. I want to get to the values for [Start]=>0 inside of the Web array.
2. I also need to go through and output the [results][0]clickurl,title etc.

   I have spent hours now trying all types of combinations to no avail. Thanks for the help!

   ```
     Array
       (
   [bossresponse] => Array
       (
           [responsecode] => 200
           [web] => Array
               (
                   [start] => 0
                   [count] => 14
                   [totalresults] => 14
                   [results] => Array
                       (
                           [0] => Array
                               (
                                   [date] => 
                                   [clickurl] => http://url.com/1
                                   [url] => http://url.com/1
                                   [dispurl] => http://url.com/1...
                                   [title] => Title of Content 1
                                   [abstract] => This is the summary, This is the summary,    This is the summary, ...
                               )

                           [1] => Array
                               (
                                   [date] => 
                                   [clickurl] => http://url.com/2
                                   [url] => http://url.com/2
                                   [dispurl] => http://url.com/2...
                                   [title] => Title of Content 2
                                   [abstract] => This is the summary, This is the summary,  This is the summary, ...
                               )
                       )

                 )

          )

   )
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo $var['bossresponse']['web']['start'];
foreach ($var['bossresponse']['web']['results'] as $result) 
  foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
    echo "$key => $value <br>";
  }
}
```

Comment: can you see my comment below and let me know what is going on, please?

Answer (score 0):

```
$json['bossresponse']['web']['start']
$json['bossresponse']['web']['results'][0]['title']
```

in foreach()

```
foreach($json['bossresponse']['web']['results'] as $j){
     echo "<br>title".$j['title'];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I was using this, but I was attempting to do so from within a foreach.